# Running executable jar file from command prompt

Tags: java

How to run a jar file which holds a java program from command prompt?

Getting following exception while trying to run

---

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainClassFromJar(Unknown Source) at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

---

Comment: Getting following exception while trying to run****Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainClassFromJar(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)***

Answer (score -1):

Just go to the directory with "cd path to jar file". 
 
And there you enter "filename.jar" and hit enter. 
For me this works fine. 

 
Edit: I put the "filename.jar" into brackets and the compiler did not show the filename.

Comment: -1: This looks rather incomplete.  As in it's missing the actual command.

Comment: I tested it before I posted the answer. And everything was fine. So it is not really incomplete. And cause he said with command prompt and no operating system: I think everything is fine! ;)

Comment: As now edited, this may work for you, but it's very OS-specific.  It's still a pretty weak answer.

Comment: OKay, I'm fine with you ;)